# Analysis Services does NOT clear the cache as instructed (dimension dynamic security)

Tags: ssas

Analysis Services 2008 R2, Enterprise 64, Version: 10.50.2500.0

Win7 64bit

I have setup the dimension dynamic security to use assembly to get the allowed members for the role/dimension. 
The assembly looks up the SQL Server database table and returns the allowed members and **logs** everything into the DB so that I can debug things more easily.

So, when I test the role (via SSMS, BIDS, Excel) the assembly gets called **only once** and then AS (as I understand it) caches the security info (i.e. security dimension).

Thus, if I change the content of the relational table with allowed members it is not reflected even if I close and reopen the apps. Fine, it's cached.

But then I instruct the AS to **CLEAR** the cache as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230974.aspx

Nothing happens. 
The XMLA query executes fine, I get:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty" />
</return>
```

but the assembly **DOES NOT** get called again, and the allowed members are wrong.
Also, these guys say that this approach should work: http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/why-not-to-use-the-external-assembly-approach-for-dynamic-security/

The only way to get it to work is to reprocess the cube!

Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround?

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: I'd like to add one more thing - I've tried the same thing with the "standard" approach, that is, without assemblies, using the bridge table and MDX statement for the AllowedMembers.
Doesn't work as advertised.
I do get the reduced members, but when I change the content of sql server bridge table, it is NOT reflected on the data.
The security is cached forever. 
I issue the XMLA clear cache statement, reconnect from the BIDS, nothing changes!
How dynamic is that!?

Comment: One more thing - I've tried setting ROLAP storage on the bridge table measure group and OLAPusers dimension, then it stopped working all together.